# Find ratio of quantities of water and of argon in airtight container

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

I am working on my [EJU exam past papers (2013)](https://www.jasso.go.jp/en/eju/examinee/pastpaper_sample/pastpaper_2013_2.html) and got stuck at this question. Knowledge of high school or first year university chemistry is assumed. I honestly do not know where I should start.

> When argon and water were placed in an airtight container with a
>   constant volume and the gas mixture was kept at 373 K, the pressure of
>   the gas mixture became P<sub>1</sub> with a portion of water remained as liquid.
>   When the whole was heated to 403 K, all the water was vaporized and
>   the pressure became P<sub>2</sub>. From (1) to (6) below choose the correct
>   formula representing the ratio, water/argon, of the quantities (in
>   mol) of water and of argon in the container. Assume that the vapor
>   pressure of water at 373 K is P<sub>v</sub>, that argon is an ideal gas not
>   dissolving in water, and that the volume of water before heating to
>   403 K can be neglected.

[image]
Please note that answer key provided is (1). I tried to think that we could form an equation from total moles of gases equate to the sum of total moles of water and argon at 403 K since all are vaporized. Then use the ideal gas law to find the total amount of gases at 403 K. However, I cannot connect these pieces and information given at 373 K together. Could anyone give me a solution to this question or at least a hint so I can continue working on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the ideal gas law to convert between $n_i$ (amount of gas) and $p/T$. For each temperature and pressure pair you can write
$$\begin{align}n_{g,1}=\frac{p_1V}{RT_1}\\n_{g,2}=\frac{p_2V}{RT_2}\end{align}$$
where
$$\begin{align}n_{g,1}&=n_{g,H_2O}+n_{Ar}\\n_{H_2O}&=n_{g,H_2O}+n_{l,H_2O}\\n_{g,2}&=n_{H_2O}+n_{Ar}\end{align}$$
You also know that for each individual gas the partial pressure is proportional to the number of moles (Dalton's law):
$$n_i=\frac{p_iV}{RT}$$
 The "trick" is that at $T_1=\pu{373K}$
$$p_{Ar} = p_1 - p_V$$
where $p_V$ is given as the partial pressure of water at that temperature.
You should be able to show that 
$$\frac{n_{H_2O}}{n_{Ar}}=\frac{n_{g,2}}{n_{Ar}}-1$$
and making appropriate substitutions it should not be difficult to arrive at the answer.